# jQuery Ajax call returning null from WCF RIA REST service

Tags: wcf, rest, jquery

I have created a [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 4 service and deployed it to a local [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) 7.
If I use [Fiddler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiddler_%28software%29) and use the request builder, I am able to call the service and see the data been returned OK. If I try hitting the same REST location in the browser, [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is not been returned but it looks like [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML).

My service looks like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{id}/details.json",
    ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public SampleItem Get(string id)
{
    return new SampleItem{ Id=1, StringValue="value from string"};
}
```

My `web.config` file has only a slight change:

```
<standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
```

I am trying to call the service using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "http://wcf-rest/service1/1/details.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) { alert(data); },
        error: function (e) { alert("error"); }
    });
}); // end .ready
```

However, null is being returned every time. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using jQuery and Ajax extensively with a JSON datatype, and I believe you need to change `data` to `data.d`. See my example below.

```
function getMakes() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../WebService_VehicleAssignment.asmx/getAllVehicleMakes",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            var response = msg.d;
            $('#output').empty();
            $.each(response, function (vehicle, vehicle) {
                $('#output').append(new Option(vehicle.Make, vehicle.Id));
            });
        },
        failure: function (msg) {
            alert('failure');
        }
    });
}<br />
```

I use [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) to debug this stuff. I can see exactly what's getting posted to the web service and what is coming back. And if the web service is complaining, what it's complaining about.

Read about why the `.d` is necessary in *[A breaking change between versions of ASP.NET AJAX](http://encosia.com/2009/02/10/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/)*. In short, I believe it is a wrapper so that returned data is treated as a string rather than being returned and executed if it is raw literal JavaScript code.

Comment: Hi Nick, I tried your suggestion however msg.d is null I tired using firebug but its not really telling me much. I wonder if its something to do with the wcf rest service not returning the data in the way that the browser requirs?

Comment: @user293545, did you set up the success function like I did? In your case it would be alert(data.d); That is the correct syntax, I wish I could help you more.